# Is there any way to debug Django apps running inside vagrant using VS Code?

Tags: django, debugging, visual-studio-code, vagrant, remote-debugging

I've been trying to debug an Open edX instance running inside their devstack using VS Code but the debugger keeps giving me the error.

`Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly`

Here is my `launch.json`

```
{
  "name": "Python: Open edX",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "attach",
  "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "remoteRoot": "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/manage.py",
  "port": 2222,
  "host": "localhost",
  "secret": "my_secret",
},
```

Also ptvsd inserted into the source code in `manage.py`

```
import ptvsd

ptvsd.enable_attach("my_secret", address = ('192.168.33.10', 8005))

ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
```